# Dashboard 100% height?

Tags: html, css, height, bootstrap-4

I'm designing a dashboard and I need it to take 100% full height of any monitor.  I've read many other posts here from Stackoverflow, I've tried the hv 100%, height:100%, and nothing will work :(  I am working with Bootstrap 4 by the way. To show the dashboard to my client I've set a fixed height for now, but I need it to take full height. I'm editing this post by sharing only the very simple HTML layout that I have, showing how much height I need for each DIV.
 [MY LAYOUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz27I.png)

Here's the code:

```html
<!-- THE ENTIRE DASHBOARD SHOULD TAKE 100% HEIGHT OF ANY SCREEN SIZE -->

<body>
    <div class="container"><!-- 100% HEIGHT -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 gray">Top Navigation</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 gray">
          Side Table: 100%
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 gray">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 gray">Box 1: 50% height</div>
            <div class="col-7 gray">Box 2: 50% height</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9 pink">Box 3: 50% height</div>
            <div class="col-3 pink">Box 4: 50% height</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please simplify the code to a minimal example.

Comment: Try setting height to `100vh` to the container. Or min-height to allow it to get bigger if it needs.

Comment: @Klooven you mean add 100vh to the main container? The <div class="container-fluid"> container?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Klooven Doesn't work :(  I don't know where my mistake is.  Any other ideas? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

add this to css

```
html, body { 
height:100%;
}
```

then make your elements fill that space by adding height: random% to them making sure each has enough space based on its parent element

Comment: Thanks. I tried and the last two <DIV>s still don't take the 50% as I wrote in my CSS. Is this because these two DIVs haven't been filled with information?  You can view it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmourad84/e6mzmk5u/#&togetherjs=hhrbCJAhsy